# Asp.net Kill request after session is closed

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, pdf, optimization

I searched threads here and couldn't really find what I wanted. I know asp.net web forms is an old technology, but I need to work on it for now. Let's say I have a method which does some heavy processing. For example, there is a function which creates 300 PDF Invoices, zip it and downloads it to user computer.

Sample Code:

```
for(int i = 1; i <= 300;i++)
{
    PrintPDF(i);
}
```

Now let's say PrintPDF takes about 30 seconds to print one record, so it will take around 150 minutes to print 300 PDFs. Now from a user point of view, I may choose to quit in between if I don't like. If user closes the browser then

1. Does the request to print PDF get aborted instantly after user closes the session?
2. If it doesn't, what can we do to ensure that the request is immediately aborted as soon as user closes the browser.

Comment: how are you printing the pdf? on client side? using javascript?

Comment: @शेखर, actually that is immaterial. I only meant to state an example where there is a function which takes lot of times in processing. That is supposed to be the server side code, if that is what you meant to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Http is stateless. That means you can never relay on fact that you'll get notification when user is closing the browser. However you can always implement [Dead man's switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dead_man%27s_switch). I.E. make a javascript that will send pings to your server every ten seconds or so & treat user that haven't sent "ping" for more than twenty seconds as logged of. As for heavy processing on server side - that's really unfortunate way to go; for instance ASP.NET have maximum time it can spend serving request - check `executionTimeout` of `httpRuntime` `web.config` element (by default 110s). You can increase this value of course - but the application pool can be recycled anyway and also if there will be lot of requests on "heavy processing" you can run out of available processing threads. If the site is accessible over internet that is also great place for DDos attack.

Better way is to create queue (in db/cloud) and windows service that will process this queue asynchronously. Still you can implement this "force kill request mechanism" by storing "close" flag in queue item that will service check periodically & will stop processing if it is set.

Other workaround is to use websockets (SignalR).

Comment: Ok, isn't SignalR or any server pings (like using pubnub) going to be too much resource incentive?

I liked the queue idea and checking the availability of session ID to ensure the request is still valid. I will try that

Comment: Yeah - web sockets can waste a lot of resources, since every user means active duplex connection between your server and client. As for javascript pings - it depends how frequently you setup the pings; since the server logic is very simple (update timestamp & return) I don't think they waste a lot of resources if the frequency is reasonable enough.